# Why is part of my path rendering thicker?

Tags: android, svg

I'm trying to get the basics of paths understood, and I'm trying to make an hourglass shape. When I try and draw the top part, kind of an upside-down `U`, the right-hand side part is thicker. What have I got wrong?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportHeight="24"
        android:viewportWidth="24">

    <group>
        <path
            android:pathData="M0,5L0,0M0,0L10,0M10,0L10,5"
            android:strokeColor="@color/ColorPrimary"
            android:strokeWidth="3"/>
    </group>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stroke extends either side of the line.

You see the entire stroke of the right hand part but only half of the stroke of the left hand part as it extends outside of the visible area since the x co-ordinate is 0, which makes the stroke occupy x co-ordinates from -1.5 to +1.5

Comment: Ahh, and because the width is 24, and I', only going to 10, the right hand side doesn't get cut off too?